# Remote debug not working. Nothing happens while attaching to process

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, .net-core, remote-debugging

I have a .NET Core project in Visual Studio 2017 on a Windows 10 computer, and I publish this project as a runtime "linux-arm" to a Linux server on the same local network.

When I run the program on Linux it works and all.

When I open "Attach to process" in VS and find the process over SSH as root user, click attach and select managed VS Studio code then a small window opens that says "Launching debug adapter". After this "attach to process" window and "launching debug adapter" window closes and nothing happens. No lines in Output or error list and no debugging.

Anything I'm missing?

Comment: I have the same problem. Still no idea how fix this.

Comment: You can activate debugger logging with "DebugAdapterHost.Logging /On /OutputWindow"

Then i got:
 1> ERROR: Debug Adapter did not respond to initial requests.
 1> ERROR: The debug adapter exited unexpectedly.
 1> ERROR: Exception while reporting error.

Comment: Hmmm i get a stack overflow exception even though the program runs fine without debugging.... i also had issuen previusely with debugger launching 64bit version on ARM prosessor so maybe that has something to do with it